# Nginx appears to be unable to connect to any upstream servers

Tags: nginx, arch-linux

We have an Nginx instance serving as a reverse proxy for a couple of domains, each hosted on their own box. Or, well, we used to. Yesterday I had barely finished updating the Nginx box with Pacman when apparently the UPC failed and the whole system lost power. When the UPC was swapped out, the system turned back on and everything worked perfectly - except Nginx.

After trying various permutations of the config file, it seems as though it's lost the ability to contact other servers, but I can't definitively confirm this because all the log says is `worker process nnn exited on signal 11 (core dumped)` and, though I've added in the lines to tell it to store the dumps, none are actually being produced. It's able to serve files stored locally, and I'm able to `curl` the other servers from the command line, but when I try accessing any domain with a `proxy_pass` entry it craps out and gives an empty response.

The install is now version 1.6.3, though I believe it was that before the update too.

**Edit:** Output of `nginx -V`:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.6.3
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --sbin-path=/usr/bin/nginx --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/lock/nginx.lock --user=http --group=http --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=stderr --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/client-body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-imap --with-imap_ssl_module --with-ipv6 --with-pcre-jit --with-file-aio --with-http_dav_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_spdy_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_addition_module --with http_degradation_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_sub_module
```

Comment: What modules are you using?  Does nginx start up without any errors? Can you post the output of "nginx -V"?

Comment: @ChadSmith I have logging enabled all the way down to the `info` level, and the only indication I can see of anything unusual is the above mentioned `signal 11` mesages.

Comment: Which linux distro are you using?  This still seems to me like a dependency has failed.

Comment: One last comment, have you made sure that your temp directories still exist and have the correct permissions after your crash?  The actual error thrown by nginx may have nothing to do with what its logging.

Comment: @ChadSmith When you asked me to grab the list of modules I noticed that the proxy module wasn't on there, which led me to the solution. Thanks for the help, however indirect. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran `pacman -Syu` again and there was another update for it. Apparently the package had accidentally been compiled without proxy support and I didn't notice.